# Multiple email addresses (send and receive) per user with a single Active Directory account?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, microsoft-office-365

The company I work for has multiple brand names e.g. **Contoso** and **Acme**

The users need to be able to send and receive emails from both **john.doe@contoso.com** and **john.doe@acme.com**

Now if John replies to an email addressed to john.doe@contoso.com, the reply address should automatically be john.doe@contoso.com (and the same for john.doe@acme.com of course)

The infra service provider we use has solved this by creating a new user in AD for John Doe, with the email address john.doe@acme.com. In Outlook John now has a completely separate mailbox for each of the brands.

Now I was hoping this could be solved without creating additional users in Active Directory.
I did some research, and I found a couple of references suggesting that proxy email addresses might be a solution

- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/sending-from-email-aliases-public-preview/ba-p/3070501
- https://www.derekseaman.com/2021/04/microsoft-365-can-now-send-email-as-proxy-address.html

**Does this proxy email solution fit our requirements, or is there a better solution?**

Requirements:

- Send and receive from both email addresses
- Reply to the same email address that was used to send the email
- No additional Active Directory Users

Comment: I'm not sure about "better solution". There aren't many solutions. Historically one way this was performed was with role-based shared mailboxes linked to a disabled account, and a separate profile and/or switching between profiles. However Microsoft stopped supporting that due to some organizations tended to make a huge mess of it. This new feature enables this capability within the client without that additional process.  The upshot is this is a managed email service, with minimal/primitive third party extensibility, so what the vendor has is your available options.

Comment: @GregAskew thanks for your comment. Would you say that the proxy email solution fulfills our requirements, and is the preferred solution?

Comment: Does this meet your requirements? Well... you haven't told us where/how your infra service provider is hosting your email. I presume they use Exchange Server based on the information in your question, but whether or not they're hosting your mailboxes on premises or in Office 365 isn't clear. If they're hosting your mailboxes in Office 365 then the first link you posted is the correct solution.

Comment: Hi, yes. For O365, just like the links you shared above, which is a good choice to meet that need, this article introduced the same thing as well: https://practical365.com/send-email-proxy-address/

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm not sure. I think they are hosting everything in O365? Thanks for you input.

Comment: Hi, any progress so far? Have you tried the method mentioned above and get your issue resolved now?

Comment: There were some complications that prevented us from using the proxy addresses. 1) the domain was hosted on another tenant, 2) the issue "reply to the same address" was apparently not solved using proxy addresses. It appears the primary email address is always used when replying. We opted for the "shared mailbox" approach; having disabled account linked to a mailbox that the regular user has access to. This is similar to something a shared mailbox like finance@acme.com for the finance department, but now only one user has access.

Comment: The proxy address should be the accepted domains of your tenant, if it's hosted by other tenant, you are not able to use it.

Comment: @joyceshen We are planning a merge of the two tenants in the future. Will revisit the proxy address solution then.

Comment: Waiting for your feedback :)